# 'Literary' usage when possessive pronoun begins sentence

Tags: possessives

I am unsure the correct wording of this question. Could anyone point me to usage notes or guidance on a construction such as this:

'Theirs was a position known to few.' Or, 'His was a car without equal.'

It seems this is a slightly more literary usage, as clearly the two examples could be rephrased as 'Their position was known to few' and 'His car was without equal.' Is this a form of inversion, which therefore gives it its feeling of being more literary?

Answer (score 1):

This is called an 'independent possessive pronoun' or an [independent possessive determiner](https://teflpedia.com/Independent_possessive_determiner) .

They also appear in other situations :

> My car is in the garage : can I borrow yours ?

Your own example is, indeed, a literary device which emphasises the importance of that which is possessed, by stating the possession independently of the thing itself.

Comment: Most uses in colloquial english are based on parallelism: "My car is really old and crappy; yours is great."

Answer (score 0):

*Fronting* is the generic term for moving to the beginning of a clause a constituent that does not normally appear there. This gives that constituent a greater emphasis than it would have in its more normal position.

[Fronting: Definition and Examples](https://www.thoughtco.com/fronting-in-grammar-1690875)

In your examples, the fronted constituents are the independent possessive pronouns *theirs* and *his*. Pronouns which precede their referents  are examples of *cataphora*, i.e. forward pointing (in this case to *position* and *car*). The much more more usual backward pointing pronouns are examples of *anaphora*.

[Cataphora in English Grammar](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-cataphora-grammar-1689829)

Comment: O.P.'s examples and rephrases all begin with the possessives, though, so this phenomenon would not seem to differentiate them.

Comment: @Brian Donovan. That's correct. But the pronouns in question are independent. And so in this case we can differentiate cataphora (_His was a car without equal_) and anaphora (_The/A car without equal was his_.)